# How are trait objects handled inside const functions?

Tags: rust, constants, constant-expression

I was trying to create an uninitialized boxed trait object wrapped inside a `MaybeUninit`.

```rust
trait Foo {}

const fn test() {
    // Error!
    let _bar: MaybeUninit<Box<dyn Foo>> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d1a4344a2dd5e14bae777d8df7a44171)

The compiler gives me the following error.

```
error[E0723]: trait bounds other than `Sized` on const fn parameters are unstable
```

I don't understand why the compiler talks about trait bounds as my function does not have any generic parameter.

I found a way around, just by wrapping the `Box<dyn Foo>` into another structure.

```rust
trait Foo {}

struct BoxedFoo(Box<dyn Foo>);

const fn test() {
    // It works!
    let _bar: MaybeUninit<BoxedFoo> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
}
```

And it works.

Why does wrapping the box makes any difference? How does first case has to do with trait bounds but not the second one?

Comment: The compiler team is very conservative about what is allowed in `const`s at the moment, and they have chosen to forbid `?Sized` bounds. A `dyn Trait` is always un-`Sized`, so that's where you warning comes from. However since a `Box<dyn Trait>` is `Sized` and the new-type trick is enough to make the compiler happy, I would just categorize that as a diagnostic issue.